# MVC authentication not occurring during request unless authorization in Web.Config

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-identity, owin

I'm using ClearTrust SSO in my MVC application.  What this means is the server provides a variable that I can access: `Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_CT_REMOTE_USER"]`

Using that variable, I'm able to login a user during the Session_Start in my Global.asax file.  However, I'm running into an issue after attempting to clean up my web.config.  We are using Owin authentication with CookieAuthentication.

If I remove this from system.web in my Web.config:

```
<authorization>
   <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

Then users are redirected by the Owin middleware to the login page which they should never see because the variable I mentioned above with their username is always available to log them in during Session_Start.

I've traced the code using breakpoints as best as I can, whether the web.config has that section or not, this code is hit on their first request which logs the user into the site:

```
var signInManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
signInManager.SignIn(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
```

The difference is that without that authorization section, Owin catches the request as not authenticated, but with it somehow the users current request is marked as authenticated (without a redirect back to the same page).  When Owin redirects them to the login page, they are obviously seeing a login page but they are logged into the site.

This is easibly fixable by adding the following code to AccountController Login, but I'm really curious as to why it happens...

```
if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
}
```

Edit: Forgot to mention why I was removing that code, I didn't think it was necessary since I'm using a global AuthorizeAttribute filter and AllowAnonymous where needed.

Comment: You shouldn't be using a web.config authorization with MVC anyways.  See the reminder at https://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/asp-net-mvc-authentication-global-authentication-and-allow-anonymous

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch That's exactly what I'm trying to remove which is causing the issue.  Please read the question.  With the web.config authorization attribute the first request isn't considered 'authenticated' by owin despite it being logged in inside Session_Start.  With it, the first request is considered authenticated.  Why?